# OAuthWebSecurity create account - how does it work?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, dotnetopenauth

I'm confused and concerned with the following line because it seems like the API for the OAuthWebSecurity has its own authentication store.

```
        // If the current user is logged in add the new account
        OAuthWebSecurity.CreateOrUpdateAccount(result.Provider, result.ProviderUserId, User.Identity.Name);
```

If I'm reading the above correctly, it seems to indicate that the API saves relationship locally.

Please tell me this is not the case, and explain what exactly does it do? I need my web application to be as stateless as possible, I cannot have API storing local values like this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It uses the `SimpleMembershipProvider` which is the default provider in ASP.NET MVC 4 to create or update the association between the public provider user id and a local user. Basically it will add a record to the `webpages_OAuthMembership` table.

Here's the corresponding code from the `WebSecurity.CreateOrUpdateOAuthAccount` that gets called:

```
public override void CreateOrUpdateOAuthAccount(string provider, string providerUserId, string userName)
{
    this.VerifyInitialized();
    if (userName.IsEmpty())
    {
        throw new MembershipCreateUserException(MembershipCreateStatus.ProviderError);
    }
    int userId = this.GetUserId(userName);
    if (userId == -1)
    {
        throw new MembershipCreateUserException(MembershipCreateStatus.InvalidUserName);
    }
    int userIdFromOAuth = this.GetUserIdFromOAuth(provider, providerUserId);
    using (IDatabase database = this.ConnectToDatabase())
    {
        if (userIdFromOAuth == -1)
        {
            if (database.Execute("INSERT INTO [" + OAuthMembershipTableName + "] (Provider, ProviderUserId, UserId) VALUES (@0, @1, @2)", new object[] { provider, providerUserId, userId }) != 1)
            {
                throw new MembershipCreateUserException(MembershipCreateStatus.ProviderError);
            }
        }
        else if (database.Execute("UPDATE [" + OAuthMembershipTableName + "] SET UserId = @2 WHERE UPPER(Provider)=@0 AND UPPER(ProviderUserId)=@1", new object[] { provider, providerUserId, userId }) != 1)
        {
            throw new MembershipCreateUserException(MembershipCreateStatus.ProviderError);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: That's crazy >.<  why would I want a membership provider that couples strongly to a database!? There should of been another layer like a service or something that can be easily extended.

Comment: Of course that there is. Feel free to use directly the `DotNetOpenAuth` library or write a custom membership provider if you don't like the default built-in functionality.

Comment: Check out the [Universal Providers 1.2](https://nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNet.Providers.Core) library MS put out -- it's supposed to be much easier to decouple.